# what happens after writing to a volatile variable?

Tags: java, volatile

I wonder if writing to a volatile variable will force jvm to synchronize all non-volatile variables to the memory, so for example, what will happen in the following code:

```java
volatile int x;
int y;

y=5; 
x=10;
```

x will be written to the memory, but what will happen to y ? will it be also written to memory ?

Comment: y is not declared as volatile...?

Comment: no, intentionally it is not declared as volatile. and the question is if writing to a volatile variable means a memory barrier for all variables.

Comment: I think it will it will depend on your version of Java...

Answer (score 5):

Yes, under the rules of [the Java Language Specification (third edition) -- in particular section 17.4.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.4) -- every thread that sees the new value of `x` will subsequently also see the new value of `y` if they try to read it. Threads that don't read `x` are not guaranteed to be affected.

Beware, however, that this guarantee was not present in the memory model of the *second* edition of JLS. There, volatile reads and writes had no effect on the ordering of non-volatile memory accesses.

Comment: For all people who aren't capable of mapping editions of the language spec to actual Java versions: This means what Henning describes is true starting from Java 1.5 upwards ;)